# Search keywords/phrases from a set in a Pandas column using Regex

Tags: regex, pandas, search, keyword

I have set of keywords and phrases, which consist of unigrams, bigrams, trigrams, four-grams, and five-grams. I would like to search for that vocabulary for that set within a Pandas DataFrame, and identify the matches of these keywords/phrases in the pandas cells.

An example of the set of keywords and phrases is found below (total length = 420):

`ccv_set = [['solar', 'energy'], ['solar', 'cell'], ['emission', 'certificate', 'credit, 'trading']...]`

So, I would like to find these  expressions
in the pandas column
, with distance 50 from each other, i.e. if the term 'solar' is 50 words away from term 'energy' the search to pick it up.  In addition, the order of appearance does not matter. To do that I have used the code below.

The code does not seem to be working correctly, i.e. not returning the ccv_set matched keywords, in either order, or distance from each other.

What is the regular expression I should be using so that the code searches through the text for the expression ['solar', 'energy'] at any position within 50 keywords and in any order?

````
ccv_set_lem = [[lmtzer.lemmatize(token) for token in sentence.split(" "), for sentence in ccv_set]]
nested_tuples_ccv_set_lem = [tuple(l) for l in ccv_set_lem]
pat_lem = '/'.join("\W+(?:\w+\W+).{0.50}?".join(x) for x in nested_tuples_ccv_set_lem
df['KW'] = df.specification_preprocess.str.findall(pat_lem)```
````

Comment: I would like this to identify the keywords in any order, i.e. solar energy or energy solar

Comment: Hi @Leo. You should update your post with a sample of your dataframe and the expected outcome for this sample as plain text to get help.